# replace placeholders in ng-include template

Tags: angularjs

In my project, I have a dynamic input form should be formed based on the JSON we are getting.  The template of the each control will be in partial html files. I will load them using ng-include. It is loading correctly.

But when comes to validation, I have some custom validation directive, they need to be added to input controls which loaded using ng-include. I tried having a place holder in template & tried replacing with my custom directives.

But I am unable to replace the place holder using ng-include.

**textbox.html**

```
<input type="text" value = "" @customValidation >
```

**Main.html**

```
<div ng-include="textbox.html"></div>
```

it should be rendered like

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value = "" ng-custom-validation="prop.value" >
</div>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: first: you write @customVali(d)ation, 
second: show your directive code, 
third: where is ng-include?

Comment: Hi Kollle, I have updated my question. I write my own custom directives & I use standard validations like required. They should be added when the JSON has that validation again that particular control.